# Llenar un input dependiendo del valor de otro

Tags: javascript, java, html

Tengo el siguiente formulario html el cual tiene un campo readonly "Precio Base" y quiero llenarlo con un valor que dependerá de los datos que tengan los otros inputs para luego validarlo con Javascript y con Java (JSP, Servlets) guardarlos en una base de datos.

```
<form class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 mx-auto form-style">
    <h1 class="text-center text-dark text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Registrar Nuevo Alquiler</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pisoOficina">Piso</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pisoOficina" placeholder="Piso" min="1" max="5">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidadSillasOficina">Cantidad de Sillas</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidadSillasOficina" placeholder="Cantidad de Sillas" min="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="frenteVentanaOficina">¿Frente a Ventana?</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="frenteVentanaOficina">
            <option>Si</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="precioBaseOficina">Precio Base</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precioBaseOficina" placeholder="Precio Base" readonly>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100">AGREGAR ALQUILER</button>
</form>
```

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa en el input de piso el valor 1, entonces automáticamente el precio base sera de 2000, pero si el usuario borra el valor 1 o lo cambia el precio base cambiara. 
Conozco formas de hacerlo con un botón "Calcular Precio" pero si existiese alguna forma de que sea automático seria lo mas adecuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar listeners al input `pisoOficina` mediante [**addEventListener**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) para manejar los eventos [**onkeyup**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) (cambios por teclado) y [**onMouseUp**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) (click en spinner). Luego, según el valor del input, setear el valor adecuado en el input `precioBaseOficina`. Tambien debes tener en cuenta el `onchange` del `select` que indica si es frente a ventana, ya que al cambiar deberías recalcular el valor.

```js
let pisoOficina = document.getElementById('pisoOficina');
let precioBaseOficina = document.getElementById('precioBaseOficina');
let frenteVentanaOficina = document.getElementById('frenteVentanaOficina');


// Listeners para recalcular el precio cuando cambia el piso

pisoOficina.addEventListener("keyup", calcularPrecio);

pisoOficina.addEventListener("mouseup", calcularPrecio);

// Listener para recalcular el precio cuando cambia el select de frente a ventana

frenteVentanaOficina.addEventListener("change", calcularPrecio);

// Función que calcula el precio en funcion del piso y si es frente a ventana.

function calcularPrecio(){
    let frenteAVentana = frenteVentanaOficina.value === "Si";
    // Si es frente a ventana agregamos $500
    let agregadoVentana = frenteAVentana ? 500 : 0;
    let piso = pisoOficina.value;
    switch(piso){
      case("1"):
         // Sumamos el precio base del piso y el agregado de ventana, que sera 500 o 0.
         precioBaseOficina.value = 2000 + agregadoVentana;
         break;
      case("2"):
        precioBaseOficina.value = 4000 + agregadoVentana;
        break;
      default:
        precioBaseOficina.value =0;

    }
}
```

```html
<form class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 mx-auto form-style">
    <h1 class="text-center text-dark text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Registrar Nuevo Alquiler</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pisoOficina">Piso</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pisoOficina" placeholder="Piso" min="1" max="5">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidadSillasOficina">Cantidad de Sillas</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidadSillasOficina" placeholder="Cantidad de Sillas" min="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="frenteVentanaOficina">¿Frente a Ventana?</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="frenteVentanaOficina">
            <option>Si</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="precioBaseOficina">Precio Base</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precioBaseOficina" placeholder="Precio Base" readonly>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100">AGREGAR ALQUILER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Faltaría el caso en que el usuario use el spinner del input

Comment: Cierto, he editado la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Marcos! Muy completa. Es muy complicado si al valor final de Precio Base le sumo un valor X dependiendo del combobox de la ventana? Intente agregando un evento de click y un switch al igual que usted pero no obtengo los resultados deseados.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para contemplar ese caso, hazme saber si no queda claro. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Con el combobox yo estaba usando el evento click y no el change. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: En realidad no hay problema con usar el click, deberia funcionar, solo que estas calculando el precio innecesariamente cuando el valor no cambia. Ademas el onclick se dispara cuando clickeas para cambiar y cuando seleccionas una opcion, o sea, dos veces, es decir.. es menos performante. Lo puedes ver en este ejemplo si abres la consola del navegador https://jsfiddle.net/a1fbso1k/